# Output of first order system does not become 0 when its input is 0 - solver settings?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am simulating the following first order system (ode45 10^-3 relative tolerance - default settings): 
[image]

The scope (magenta - square wave, yellow - filter output):
[image]

The pulse generator makes a square wave. The funny thing is that the output of the first order system does not become 0 when its input is 0 (when the square wave comes back to 0).

I guess it's a solver issue. Have you seen this before? I have some 0 comparisons in my code so I should change those to some tolerance levels. Is this a good solution? Or should I change the solver settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in another answer, the problem here is that you are letting the solver take too large a time step.  The default "maximum step size" is set to "auto".  What this means is a step size of (StopTime-StartTime)/50.  You seem to have set a large Stop Time, and hence the max step size is very large.

If you need to run the simulation for a long time then you need to change the step size from its default to something much smaller.

Comment: Thanks for the formula. I did not know that.

Comment: @remus That was in my answer as well, although I got it slightly wrong in that I said divided by 20 instead of 50.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is because the frequency of the square wave is too fast and there's not enough time for the system dynamics to come back to to zero. Try reducing the frequency of the square wave.

You might also want to specify a maximum step size in the solver settings other than the default to improve the resolution of the plot (e.g. 1s). The default max step size is the simulation stop time divided by 20 so it can be quite coarse.

Comment: No. The frequency is actually slow. It should be 0 instead of those spikes (the square wave is 0 almost for the entire image in the scope). The period of the square wave is 140s.

Comment: I'll add a better image - also with the square wave.

Comment: I made an update with the scope image showing the square wave too.

Comment: OK. Have you tried setting the max step size to say 1s? Maybe also try a different solver, such as ode15s.

Comment: I noticed a reduction of the spikes with respect to the relative tolerance parameter for the solver but it won't go to 0 even though the input into the block is 0. I was expecting it to be 0 because the block input is 0.

Comment: I'm convinced this is because the solver is taking too large time steps. Try setting the max step size to 1s, as already suggested (in solver configuration)